# React useState starts bugging after multiple state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

Im working on a cookie clicker type game and Im working on making features like automatic clickers / combo multipliers. I created the start of the game but when I use my auto function it begins bugging after multiple clicks of the clicker. I have linked the code and an example of the bug occurring below.

**CODE**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from "react-native";

import { cases } from "./cases";

import { motion } from "framer-motion";

const io = require("socket.io-client");
const SocketEndpoint = "http://localhost:3000/";

const App = () => {
  const [cash, setCash] = useState(0);
  const [clicks, setClicks] = useState(0);
  const [bot, setBot] = useState(0);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [prize, setPrize] = useState(null);
  const [connected, setConnected] = useState(false);
  const [upgrades, setUpgrades] = useState({auto: false, multi: false})
  const [multi, setMulti] = useState(1);
  let applied = false;
  
  useEffect(() => {[![enter image description here][1]][1]
    const socket = io(SocketEndpoint, {
      transports: ["websocket"],
    });

    socket.on("connect", () => {
      setConnected(true)
    });
  }, [])  

  useEffect(() => {
    if(!applied) {
      autoUpgrade();
      applied = true;
    }
  }, [bot, upgrades])

  const autoUpgrade = () => {
    if (!upgrades.auto) {
      return;
    }

    const inter = setInterval(() => setBot(bot + 1), 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(inter);
  }

  const collectBotIncome = () => {
    setCash(cash + bot);
    setBot(0);
  }

  const addMulti = () => {
    if (!upgrades.multi) {
      return;
    }
    setMulti(2)
  }

  const increasePoint = () => {
    setClicks(clicks + (1 * multi))
  }

  const purchaseCase = () => {
    setClicks(clicks - 10)
  }

  const purchaseUpgrade = (upgrade) => {
    alert('purchased')
    
    upgrade === 'auto' ? setUpgrades({...upgrades, auto: true}) : null;
    upgrade === 'multi' ? setUpgrades({...upgrades, multi: true}) : null;
  }

  const between = (x, min, max) => {
    return x >= min && x <= max;
  }

  const openCase = () => {
    setOpen(true);
    purchaseCase();

    const ticket = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
    console.log('[ROUND] Ticket:' + ticket)
    var found = false;
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < cases.types[0].items.length; i++) {
      var item = cases.types[0].items[i];

      if(between(ticket, item.ticketStart, item.ticketEnd)) {
        setPrize(item.name)

        found = true;
      }
    }
  }

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <View style={styles.shopMenu}>
          <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>Shop</Text>

          <Text onClick={() => purchaseUpgrade('auto')} style={{color: 'white'}}>Auto Click Level 1</Text>
          <Text onClick={() => purchaseUpgrade('multi')} style={{color: 'white'}}>Click Multiplier Level 1</Text>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.shopMenu}>
          <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>Inventory</Text>

          {upgrades.auto
            ? 
              <>
                <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>{bot}</Text>
                <Text onClick={collectBotIncome} style={{color: 'white'}}>Collect Bot Income</Text>
              </>
            : null
          }
        </View>
        
        <motion.img
          whileHover={{ scale: 1.1 }}
          whileTap={{ scale: 0.9 }}
          onClick={increasePoint}
          src={require('./src/assets/case.png')} alt="case"
        />
        <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>clicks: {clicks ? clicks : "0"}</Text>
        <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>connected: {connected ? "true" : "false"}</Text>



        {open 
          ? <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>{prize ? prize : 'Failed to get Prize'}</Text>
          : <Image
            style={clicks >= 10 ? styles.available : styles.unavailable}
            source={require('./src/assets/case.png')} alt="case"
            onClick={openCase}
          />
        }

        <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>{cases.types[0].name}</Text>
      </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "black",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  available: {
    display: 'flex',
    width: 150,
    height: 100,
    filter: 'none',
    transition: '200ms ease',
    marginTop: 50
  },
  unavailable: {
    display: "flex",
    width: 150,
    height: 100,
    filter: 'grayscale(1)',
    transition: '200ms ease',
    marginTop: 50
  },
  shopMenu: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column"
  }
});

export default App;
```

**PREVIEW**

[image]